# Internal mod_rewrite, no redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to make an internal redirect from one URL to another using mod_rewrite in my .htaccess file. Currently I know how to perform the external redirect with the following:

```
RewriteRule ^incoming-controller/action1.*$ http://example.com/incoming-controller/action2 [R=301,L]
```

I want this to happen internally, so the user posts to action1 while apache internally serves the request to action2. Is this possible? I have read about the [P] flag and mod_proxy but I haven't been able to find much documentation on how to use it properly, or if it's useful in this situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove the `R=301` from the flag. This is what causes the external redirect.

You will also need to not use the full URL like http://example.com.  Just use the URI for the resource you want to redirect to.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work, it's still performing the redirection in the browser.

`RewriteRule ^incoming-controller/action1.*$ http://example.com/incoming-controller/action2 [L]`

Comment: apache access logs show it's receiving a 302 status code and redirecting.

Comment: You need to remove the `http://example.com` part as well since this is internal to the same server.